# Unable to rotate guides in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, guides

I am following this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywnMo2ZNQGM

but my guides retain horizontal or vertical and don't rotate. When I activate `Rotate` tool I can only move cyan rotation center, but can't rotate guides.

What can be done?

AI is 23.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Make certain guides are **Unlocked** - `View > Guides > Lock` should **not** be checked.

---

Guide locking defaults are *very* dependent upon the *version* of AI one is using. Some versions will lock guides by default, other versions won't.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the giude you want to select is not locked, and active when you use the rotate tool. The active guide will be a different color than the non-active guides.

In my version of CS5 Illustrator I can check if guides are locked or not by going to the "View" menu, then navigating down to the "Guides" option.

You should also be able to set the center point for the rotation.
[image: Adobe Illustrator guides example]